# How to get session in all pages.? codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

Here I want to use session in my all pages any one can help me on this topic. some says create a custom controller in library, and/or use helper/hook, I don't know what will work.

If any one have a little example code and little desc. then please share here. 
How can I use session in all pages.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the CodeIgniter documentation

> Sessions will typically run globally with each page load, so the
>   Session class should either be initialized in your controller
>   constructors, or it can be auto-loaded by the system. For the most
>   part the session class will run unattended in the background, so
>   simply initializing the class will cause it to read, create, and
>   update sessions when necessary.
>
> To initialize the Session class manually in your controller
>   constructor, use the $this->load->library() method:
>
> ```
> $this->load->library('session');
> ```

So, in order to initialize the Session library in ALL your controllers, the best idea is to have a custom "general controller"

```
<?php
class MyController extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->library('session');
        }
}
```

and then have all your contollers extend not the default CI_Controller, but your "MyContoller", like in

```
<?php
class Blog extends MyController {

        public function index()
        {
                echo 'Hello World!';
        }
}
```

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: where should I put  MYcontroller.php file.? in controller folder or core folder.?

Comment: In your controller folder.